# Price slider showing [object Object] after initialisation

Tags: javascript, vue.js, object, initialization, slider

I am working on a price slider in Vue where via an API-call all product data is returned. In one of the objects, the range between the lowest and the highest price of all the items is returned.

The code for the slider implementation in my .Vue class is:

```
        <price-slider
          code="price"
          id="reloadDiv"
          :priceRange="[{ from: minPrice }, { to: maxPrice }]"
          @change="$emitPriceSlider($event)"
        />
```

Whenever I drag the first slider-option, the [object Object] is instantly set to the end including the correct price. Clicking the first slider-option then, also sets the correct (first and lowest) price.

I can not seem to find why the price-slider option are not set to the correct position and vlaue, but just show [object, Object] on top of each other and wondered if someone could enlighten me.
I also tried adding forceUpdate() to the element but could not seem to get that to work.

The code for the slider component itself is as follows:

```
<template>
  <div class="price-slider-container">
    
    {{ getMin }} {{ getMax }}
    <no-ssr placeholder="loading..." placeholader-tag="span">
      <vue-slider
        ref="priceSlider"
        v-model="value"
        v-bind="priceSliderOptions"
        :clickable="false"
        :min="getMin"
        :max="getMax"
        :tooltip-formatter="tooltipContent"
        @drag-end="setPrice"
      />
    </no-ssr>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import NoSSR from "vue-no-ssr";
import isEqual from "lodash-es/isEqual";
import { products } from "config";

const PriceSliderComponents = {};

if (process.browser) {
  let VueSlider = require("vue-slider-component");
  PriceSliderComponents["vue-slider"] = VueSlider;
}
PriceSliderComponents["no-ssr"] = NoSSR;

export default {
  name: "PriceSlider",
  props: {
    content: {
      type: null,
      default: "",
    },
    id: {
      type: null,
      required: true,
    },
    code: {
      type: null,
      required: true,
    },
    priceRange: {
      type: Array,
      required: true,
    },
    context: {
      type: null,
      default: "",
    },
  },
  beforeMount() {
    this.$bus.$on("reset-filters", this.resetPriceSlider);
    this.$bus.$on("reset-price-slider", this.resetPriceSlider);
  },
  beforeDestroy() {
    this.$bus.$off("reset-filters", this.resetPriceSlider);
    this.$bus.$off("reset-price-slider", this.resetPriceSlider);
  },
  mounted() {
    const routeQueryData =
      this.$store.state.route[products.routerFiltersSource];
    if (routeQueryData.hasOwnProperty("price")) {
      const routePriceRange = routeQueryData["price"].split("-");
      if (!isEqual(this.value, routePriceRange)) {
        this.value = routePriceRange;
      }
    }
  },
  data() {
    return {
      active: false,
      remove: false,
      value: this.priceRange,
      currencySign: this.$store.state.config.i18n.currencySign,
      priceSliderOptions: {
        clickable: false,
        height: 2,
        "bg-style": {
          backgroundColor: "#f2f2f2",
        },
        "tooltip-dir": ["bottom", "bottom"],
        formatter: "€ {value}",
        "process-style": {
          backgroundColor: "#4dba87",
          fontWeight: 700,
        },
        "tooltip-style": {
          backgroundColor: "#4dba87",
          color: "#ffffff",
          "border-color": "#4dba87",
          padding: "7px 10px",
        },
      },
    };
  },
  computed: {
    // priceSliderOptions() {
    //   return {
    //     ...this.priceSliderConfig,
    //     ...this.tooltipContent,
    //     silent: true,
    //   };
    // },
    tooltipContent() {
      return { formatter: this.currencySign + " {value}" };
    },
    getMin() {
      return String(this.priceRange[0].from);
    },
    getMax() {
      return String(this.priceRange[1].to);
    },
  },
  watch: {
    $route: "validateRoute",
  },
  methods: {
    setPrice: function (e) {
      let val = e.val;
      let from = parseInt(val[0]);
      let to = parseInt(val[1]);
      let id = from.toFixed(1) + "-" + to.toFixed(1);
      this.remove = isEqual([from, to], this.priceRange);
      this.switchFilter({
        id: id,
        type: this.code,
        from: from,
        to: to,
        remove: this.remove,
      });
    },
    switchFilter(variant) {
      this.$emit("change", variant);
    },
    resetPriceSlider() {
      if (this.$refs.priceSlider) {
        this.$refs.priceSlider.setValue(this.priceRange);
      }
    },
    validateRoute() {
      const routeQueryData =
        this.$store.state.route[products.routerFiltersSource];
      if (this.$refs.priceSlider && !routeQueryData.hasOwnProperty("price")) {
        this.$nextTick(() => {
          this.$refs.priceSlider.setValue(this.priceRange);
        });
      }
    },
  },
  components: PriceSliderComponents,
};
</script>

<style lang="scss" scoped>
@import "~src/themes/default/css/variables/colors";
@import "~src/themes/default/css/helpers/functions/color";
$color-event: color(tertiary);
$color-active: color(accent);

.price-slider-container {
  padding-bottom: 50px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}

.price-selector {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;

  &.active {
    .square {
      background-color: $color-active;
    }
  }
}

.square {
  width: 80%;
  height: 80%;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
</style>

<style lang="scss">
.vue-slider-component .vue-slider-dot {
  box-shadow: none;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should try to add a toString in the return from the get in method

Comment: I added String() to both the getMin and getMax methods, fixed the [object Object] error!! Facing another problem now, but the object error has been resolved.